# Solve for polynomial Given Zeros

Tags: polynomials

If the two solutions of a polynomial are $4$ and $6 - \sqrt{7}$, how would you solve for the polynomial?

To start would you write the expanded form as $(x-4)$ and  $(x-(6-\sqrt{7})$ and then multiply?

Comment: Yes, that gives you a polynomial with those roots.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The polynomials for with exactly those two roots are precisely those of the form $c(x-4)^a(x-(6 - \sqrt{7}))^b$, for $a, b \geq 1$ integers and $c$ any real number. With further restrictions (integer polynomials, the degrees of the roots, whatever else), you could narrow that down, potentially to a single solution.

Comment: For what it's worth: You can't have $6-\sqrt7$ be a root of a polynomial with integer (or rational) coefficients without also having $6+\sqrt7$ as a root.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, that's just what was provided.